# Does Access Control Filter implementation work for REST API?

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

I tried finding out from the documentation but it is not mentioned and from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27482685/3128638) it should work fine with REST API. Here is my code which returns status code 401 whenever I do not send access token with my request.

```
    public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'compositeAuth' => [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
            'authMethods' => [
                QueryParamAuth::className(),
        ],
        ],
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['index', 'logout'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Both `actionIndex` and `actionLogout` require access token on my query though I want only logout to do this. My controller extends my base class which extends `\yii/rest/Controller`